# База данных sqlite на ПК

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть sqlite база данных, используемая на Android. Нужно реализовать программу на C# для чтения этих данных, возможно, передача этих данных на ПК. Подскажите, какие источники почитать и в каком направление двигаться.

Comment: Почитайте ответы по этой ссылке: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465380/does-c-android-and-sqlite-work-together

Comment: @HermannZheboldov спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь можно точнее описать вопрос. Одно дело чтение данных из базы данных как из файла, который на локальном диске. Другое дело когда есть транспортный уровень, то есть когда SQLite база находится на другом ресурсе и надо как-то организовывать прослойку взаимодействия.

Comment: @AndreyK., Да, база находится на другом ресурсе

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста ситуацию, что это за ресурс. Она на мобильном устройстве? Думаю, если более подробно описать вопрос, то народ скорее поможет.

Comment: @AndreyK., Да, извините. Есть приложение, написанное знакомым для Android. Считывает QRcode, считанные данные, сохраняет в локальной бд SQLite.

Comment: @Straider вам надо определиться хотите ли  вы сделать передачу базы данных (или данных) из андроида на пк и там уже читать как угодно, или же чтобы программа на пк напрямую работала с хранилищем в андроиде. Для первого случая вариантов много - синхронизация, экспорт, ведение базы в общедоступном месте (sdcard) хотя бы, откуда это все можно унести на пк. А для второго надо мудрить работу через usb-кабель либо по сети.

Comment: @vitidev, для первого случая не подскажите подходящую литературу или статьи?

Comment: у вас слишком туманная задача. если просто перенос базы на комп, то вариантов "в лоб": 1) файлменеджером с рутом забрать на комп 2) по адб зайти и забрать на комп. 3) попросить знакомого написать экспорт в любой формат 4) попросить знакомого вести бд на scard откуда ее можно забрать без рутов и прочего (или вообще напрямую работать из c# по, ведь карта монтируется на букве диска).

Comment: @HermannZheboldov Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.